# Way to get resolve "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, jsonp

Hi guys I am doing project in html, jquery (localhost) to retrieve data from Server it is already running in localhost.

When I run below url in browser (default method is GET for browser) url_bar, I got the output perfectly in JSON format.

```
http://localhost:8080/xxx/yyy/st.json?callback=callback&_=1419402270660
```

But, when I call the above url in html file (calling implicitly the appropriate .js file) 
ajax like below code :

```
var url_var = "http://localhost:8080/xxx/yyy/st.json";
            $.ajax({
            url : url_var,
            method : "GET",
            headers : {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            },
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonpCallback: 'callback',
            success : function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            failure : function() {
                    alert("failure");
            },
            error   : function(){
            }
        });
```

I got below error in console of browser

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : st.json?callback=callback&_=1419400635006:1**

Reason for "jsonp" format used in ajax is that to return the servlet response without the conflict of **"Cross browser domain issue"** .
Any way to resolve this. Alternate way also welcome. Thanks in advance guys.....

Comment: Can you post the response from that `st.json` ?

Comment: Why are you using JSONP here? Try changing to just JSON, and removing the jsonpCallBack argument. You can then use the standard success and failure methods to complete actions once the request has returned.

Comment: try this `callback=JSON_CALLBACK`

Comment: If Json format used, I got below error <b> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/xxx/yyy/st.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. </b>. This is due to Cross browser domain, so I used "Jsonp" format

Comment: @MiG  how to use "callback=JSON_CALLBACK" in above code. Please guide ..

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/xxx/yyy/st.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK`

Comment: In my console error , ":1" has attached in my callback, though i didn't attached it. Guessing that may be rootcause. Hence the case it appearing as Unexpected token :. Any suggestion ...

Comment: @MiG same error repeating, evenafter adding that callback=JSON_CALLBACK code..